# Sending data from Django Function to Javascript (no refreshing)

Tags: javascript, html, django, http

I have a django function

```
@csrf_exempt
def postdata(request):
    r = requests.post(url ,headers=headers, auth=auth, data=json.dumps(data))
    return HttpResponse(r)
```

I want to pass r which is a dictionary response from a api to my page main.html

```
def main(request):
    return render(request, 'livestream/main.html')
```

how can I pass 'r' into a previously loaded page? Main.html calls postdate with an ajax call. I would prefer if main.html doesn't refresh, but I'm ok if it has to.

I'm not sure if it matters, but I'm using a mysql server

Thanks

Comment: You want to post from `livestream/main.html` with ajax to your `postdata` view?

Comment: I've already done that. I want to view on main.html a json object that was created in postdate

Comment: So why not just have `postdata` return json after you post to it?

Comment: That's exactly what I'm trying to do, but I can't figure out how to return json and how to access the json in my js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**views.py**

```
# data should be a list of dictionaries and not a queryset
return HttpResponse(json.dumps(data), content_type="application/json")
```

**livestream/main.html**

```
$.ajax({
  success: function(data) {
    console.log(data); // here is your server response
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change your view to return JSON:

```
import json

from django.http import HttpResponse


@csrf_exempt
def postdata(request):
    r = requests.post(url ,headers=headers, auth=auth, data=json.dumps(data))
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(r, ensure_ascii=False),
        content_type='application/json')
```

Then use that JSON to do whatever you need on the client-side.